# Not allow any null values in resultset MDX

Tags: mdx

I want to exclude any rows where there is a null value in my MDX query. Sounds simple enough:

```
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY{
 ....
 }
 ON 0
etc...
```

However, one of my columns has values even though the other ones only contain null vales. 
Example:

```
Area | ComputerSales | Areadirector
WA     (Null)             Steve
NY     21312              Mary
```

How do I remove the first row, where there is a (null) value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Computer Sales]
   ,[Measures].[Areadirector]
  } ON 0
 ,[AreaDimension].[Area].[Area] HAVING 
  (NOT 
    IsEmpty([Measures].[Computer Sales])) ON 1
FROM [YourCube];
```

Or make the set in a `WITH` clause first:

```
WITH 
  SET [S] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      [AreaDimension].[Area].[Area]
     ,[Measures].[Computer Sales]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Computer Sales]
   ,[Measures].[Areadirector]
  } ON 0
 ,[S] ON 1
FROM [YourCube];
```

Second approach is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example FILTER and ISEMPTY function

```
SELECT
      [Measures].[Fac Count] on 0,
FILTER(
       [Time].[Date Key].children,
       NOT ISEMPTY([Measures].[Fac Count])
       )
       on 1
FROM
   [Test]
```

this simple query returns only date keys that Fac Count measure has non empty value.

Comment: Filter() is going to likely be a lot slower than @whytheq's NonEmpty() answer.